# Paypal use of clientid & clientSecret for PHP

Tags: php, paypal, clientid

I am using Paypal API for a long time for developing.

Now, my site is on life, and I have problems, of migrating my code to life,
and I presume that I need add clientid+clientSecret, which I didn't have on developing site.

(As I see on https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php and by some workarround).

Also, I want minimal changes on the code bellow, even it seems old fashioned to have it worked in life web site.

As developer, I use "setExressCheckout" method like this
(Attention to echo $response - I don't expect that line. What to do instead?)

// =========== START OF CODE

```
<?php

/*.
require_module 'standard';
    require_module 'standard_reflection';
    require_module 'spl';
    require_module 'mysqli';
    require_module 'hash';
    require_module 'session';
    require_module 'streams';
.*/

    require_once __DIR__ . "/stdlib/all.php";

/*. array .*/ $body_data = null;

$body_data_txt = "";

/*. string .*/ $htmlpage  = "";

/*. array .*/ $tokenAr = array();

$response = "";

session_start();

$url = trim('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');

$body_data = array( 'USER' => "*******",
                    'PWD' => "*******",                                    
                    'SIGNATURE' => "******",
                    'VERSION' => "95.0",
                    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => "Sale",
                    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => (string)$_SESSION["AMOUNT"],
                    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
                    'RETURNURL' => "*****",
                    'CANCELURL' => "******",
                    'METHOD' => "SetExpressCheckout"
                                );

$body_data_txt = http_build_query($body_data, '', chr(38));
try
{
    //create request and add headers
    $params = array(
        'http' => array(
            'protocol_version' => "1.1",
            'method' => "POST",
            'header' => "".
            "Connection: close\r\n".
            "Content-Length: ".strlen($body_data_txt)."\r\n".
            "Content-type: "."application/x-www-form-urlencoded"."\r\n",
            'content' => $body_data_txt
    ));

    //create stream context
     $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

    //open the stream and send request
    try {
        $fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $ctx);
    } catch(ErrorException $e) {
        throw new ErrorException("cannot open url" . $url . " error:" . $e->getMessage());
    }
     //get response
     $response = (string)stream_get_contents($fp);
     //check to see if stream is open
     if ($response === "") {
        throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
     }

     //close the stream
     fclose($fp);   

     $key = explode("&", $response);
     if (substr($response, 0, 1) === "<") {
        echo $response; // ******************************
     }
     ....
```

// ============ END OF CODE

The code doesn't work as expected, since the line 'echo $response ...' should not run.
It has the contents of a screen titled:

"No buyers or sellers

Sign up for free.

...
"

As I investigated, I need client-id and client-secret. That I made on https://developer.paypal.com.
But how to use it - with minimal changes on my code?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for my question - No need for clientid and clientsecret.

The code work same for developing mode and life mode.

The url was wrong, and should be: $url = trim('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');

Thanks, anyway :)